# Is there a better way to toggle Bootstrap form errors with Angular other than really long ng-class attributes?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form that allows the user to change their password.

[image]

I have two directives I'm using to validate my form:

- Does the password adhere to a specific format (8 char length, 1 letter, 1 number)
- Do the new password boxes and the confirm password boxes match in input

The directives check for validity on the ngModel of the element and the set the validity so that I can see in the view with formName.modeName.$error.

I display an error message and toggle in the input boxes to have the `has-error` bootstrap class to change them red.

The problem with this is I end up with these extremely long `ng-class` attributes to determine whether or not to add `has-error`:

```
<div data-ng-class="{'has-error' : changePasswordForm.newPassword.$invalid && changePasswordForm.newPassword.$dirty || changePasswordForm.confirmPassword.$invalid && changePasswordForm.newPassword.$dirty && changePasswordForm.confirmPassword.$dirty}" class="form-group">
```

The example above is saying to add the `has-error` class if:

- New password field is dirty and the format of the password is wrong
- New password field and confirm password field are both dirty and the inputs don't match

Is this the Angular way? This makes the templates really hard to read for me. How should I be doing this?

Edit: In other words, should I be handling this logic in the template itself like I am doing, or should I be using toggle class in a directive or something similar?

---

Comment: What is the mark up you are wanting to change? What div are you adding the ngClass to?

Comment: @CalebWilliams The ngClass is being added to all of the from-group divs. The example from the post is for the 'New Password' form group (label and input)

Comment: Couldn't you just move the logic to your controller?
Determine the validity there (check all the dirty and invalid stuff) and pass one simple to use value to your $scope.

Comment: @JasperZelf is that considered good practice to handle that kind of logic in the controller? I am brand new to Angular.

Comment: I think it is if it benefits readability...

Answer (score 2):

You could add a directive to flag the `has-error class`, like this one ([Bootstrap Form Validation Done Right in AngularJS](http://blog.yodersolutions.com/bootstrap-form-validation-done-right-in-angularjs/)):

```
angular.module('app', []).
  directive('showErrors', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function(scope, el) {
        el.bind('blur', function() {
          var valid = // is valid logic
          el.toggleClass('has-error', valid);
        });
      }
    }
  });
```

[ngMessages](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMessages/directive/ngMessages) also has tools to solve this problem for the associated messages.

Answer (score 1):

The best way I can think to accomplish this would be to write a custom directive for this:

```
<div class="form-group" validate-class="confirmPassword"> ... </div>
```

And in your directive

```
.directive('validateClass', [function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function validateClassLink(scope, element, attributes, ngForm) {
            var fieldObj    = ngForm[attributes.validateClass],
                className   = attributes.errorClass || 'has-error';

            scope.$watch(function() {
                return (fieldObj.$invalid && fieldObj.$dirty);
            }, function(conditionMet) {
                element.toggleClass(className, conditionMet);
            });
        },
        require: '^form'
    };
}]);
```

This is pretty rudimentary, but it should accomplish what you need.

Comment: Updated to make it quite a bit more elegant.